# how to keep modal open if there are errors

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

I would like to let the modal keep open if there are errors,but the modal will not auto open when there are errors

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   

 @if($errors->any())
       <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#modal-title').modal('show');   
            });   
     </script>              
  @endif
```

modal

```
    <form action="/employee" class="action" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-scroll" aria-labelledby="modal-title" id="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true"
            x-show="open">
```

Comment: Could you add your modal code as well? Also you are importing JQuery twice. You should remove one of the two. Otherwise it'll cause issues.

Comment: @Siddharth Bhansali, modal code added and already deleted one JQuery but still cannot

Comment: How are you opening the `modal` normally, when trying to fill the form?

Comment: @ Siddharth Bhansali
 set x-data ="{open:true}" and put this @click="open = true" at the button

Comment: @Siddharth Bhansali actually I want to use $watch but it failed
 x-data="{  open: false, modal_1_open:false,modal_fam_open:false,modal_edu_open:false,modal_exp_open:false, errors:{{ $errors }}}" x-init="$watch('errors', value => console.log('have errors'))"

Comment: Hmm ok, I will update here if I can find a solution!

Comment: @ Siddharth Bhansali
Okay,thank you very much!!